# os.copy - in current directory - one file to another not working

Tags: python-3.x, windows, copy

So I have these files in a directory:

```
file1.txt
demo.py
```

I then run this code (demo.py):

```
import os
os.system("copy file1.txt file2.txt")
```

But I get this:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Just a point. If I do

```
copy file1.txt file2.txt
```

In the command prompt - it works fine. What's the deal? Do I need to reference the file fully when using os.copy on Windows?

Comment: Apparently the working directory is a UNC path. Don't assume it's the directory that contains "demo.py". Your script can be started with any working directory. Change to the script directory explicitly via `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`. Verify this with `print(os.getcwd())`.

Answer (score 0):

os.system() is not recommended to execute shell commands. Try this:

```
import subprocess  
cmd = "copy file1.txt file2.txt" 
execute = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)  
print('output', execute)
```